# Set date format with lubridate in R shiny

Tags: r, date, shiny, modifier

I am trying to set the date format of a csv input in a shiny app, but I get really lost. I've seen many things using `switch` the same way I am but is going like this:

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
   theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),             

   # Navigation bar
   navbarPage("Let's do some analysis!",

              # Upload Tab
              tabPanel("Upload",
                       sidebarPanel(
                             fileInput(inputId = "data", label = "Choose CSV Data Set",
                                       accept = c(                                                           
                                         "text/csv",
                                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                         ".csv")
                             ), #fileInput - data

                             checkboxGroupInput("sep1", h5("Separator"), choices = list(";" = ";" , "," = ",")),

                             fileInput(inputId = "stopwords", label = "Choose CSV Stopwords File",
                                       accept = c(
                                         "text/csv",
                                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                         ".csv")
                             ),#fileInput - stopwords

                             checkboxGroupInput("sep2", h5("Separator"), choices = list(";" = ";" , "," = ",")),

                             checkboxGroupInput("date", h5("Date format"), choices = list("ymd" = 1 , "mdy" = 2, "dmy" = 3, "ydm" = 4)),
                             h5("y = year, m = month, d = day"),

                           ), #sidebarPanel - Upload
                           mainPanel(
                             DT::dataTableOutput("data"),
                             h5("Please make sure you selected each separator accurately and take a look at how 'File.Date' is displayed!"),
                             br(),
                             DT::dataTableOutput("stopwords")
                           ) #maiPanel - Upload
              ), #tabPanel - Upload

              # Analizing & Modeling Tab 
              tabPanel("Analizing & Modeling",
                       fluidRow(
                         column(6,
                                visOutput('LDAvis')),
                         column(6,
                                DT::dataTableOutput("top_abstracts"), downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Top Abstracts per topic"))

                       )#fluidRow

              )#tabPanel - Analizing & Modeling 

   ) # navbarPage
 ) #fluidPage

 server <- function(input, output, session) {

   og_data <- eventReactive(input$data,{
     inFile1 <- input$data
     if (is.null(inFile1)) {
       return(NULL)
     } else {
       return(read.csv(inFile1$datapath, sep = input$sep1, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)) 
     }
   }) # eventReactive - og_data

   og_data <- eventReactive(input$date,{
     switch (input$date,
       1 = ymd(og_data()$File.Date),
       2 = mdy(og_data()$File.Date),
       3 = dmy(og_data()$File.Date),
       4 = ydm(og_data()$File.Date)
     ) 
   }) # eventReactive - innog_data with accurate date format

   stopwords <- eventReactive(input$stopwords,{
     inFile2 <- input$stopwords
     if (is.null(inFile2)) {
       return(NULL)
     } else {
       return(read.csv(inFile2$datapath, sep = input$sep2, header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)) 
     }
   }) # eventReactive - stopwords

   # Upload tab

   output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({
     DT::datatable(og_data(), options = list(pageLength = 1, lengthMenu = c(1,3)))
   })

   output$stopwords <- DT::renderDataTable({
     DT::datatable(stopwords())
   })
 } #server function
```

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing you're doing wrong is posting the console output. You should post the code itself, not the console output, otherwise when we copy and paste your code it's filled with '+' signs!

Comment: You can't use switch with numeric parameter names. This will produce a syntax error: `x <- 1; switch(x, 1="ok")` but this will not `x <- 1; switch(x, "1"="ok")`. Normally if you are just matching on index you would leave the `1=` part off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function argument names, including the options for `switch`, need to be valid object names. Standard object names don't start with numbers. So the issue with `1 = ymd(og_data()$File.Date)` is that `1` isn't a valid object name.

```
x = 1
switch(x, 1 = "hi")
# Error: unexpected '=' in "switch(x, 1 ="
```

You could use backticks around the numbers to make them non-standard names:

```
x = 1
switch(x, `1` = "hi")
# [1] "hi"
```

Or (preferred), you could use standard variable names that are also descriptive. This is clearer and less bug-prone.

```
...
choices = list("ymd", "mdy", "dmy" , "ydm")
...
switch (input$date,
       "ymd" = ymd(og_data()$File.Date),
       "mdy" = mdy(og_data()$File.Date),
       "dmy" = dmy(og_data()$File.Date),
       "ydm" = ydm(og_data()$File.Date)
     ) 
...
```

Comment: It shows this error, even tho I know it is 'ymd' & I do it in the reg console and it works perfectly fine: `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3363
Warning: Error in format.default: invalid 'trim' argument
  [No stack trace available]`

Comment: Perhaps ask a new question sharing a reproducible example. I don't know how to help with that without some sample input to test on.